# How to enable users editing their CiviCRM profiles details from their Drupal user page?

Tags: civicrm

I have a new Drupal7 instance with CiviCRM integrated. I have successfully linked CiviCRM contacts (specifically CiviMember members) to users in Drupal with the role of 'member'.

I want members to login and edit their CiviCRM profile. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: To make sure, you are using [this module](http://drupal.org/project/civicrm)? If not, how did you get things you mentioned to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a CiviCRM Profile (or reuse one of the existing ones) by going to Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Profiles and set it to be enabled on "View/Edit Drupal User Account". Then the user will be able to edit their details from their Drupal user page.

See this [Demo Profile on CiviCRM Demo site](http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group/update?action=update&id=1&context=group) and notice that "View/Edit Drupal User Account" is checked. Take a look at [this tab on the Drupal user page](http://drupal.demo.civicrm.org/user/4/edit/Name%20and%20Address). The fields in the Profile can be edited.

For more details see: [the CiviCRM book section on Profiles](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/).

Comment: Sam Williams, Please consider supporting  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm so there can be a dedicated SE site for CiviCRM questions. We only need a few more people like you with over 200 on a different site to commit before we get to launch. Thanks!